# Python bs4: If entry A has “form-groups”, scrape it; for entries other than A, don't scrape “form-groups”

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to scrape information off the Oxford dictionary. The problem is that there are same class name for the class "form-groups".

I only want to scrape the class "form-groups" above the entry 1. For the word "acclimatize", my code works.

But for the word "peculiar", it scrapped the class "form-groups" under entry 2, which is not what I want. I only want to scrape the class "form-groups" above the entry 1.

So basically:

If "form-groups" above the entry 1 doesn't exist, print("none"); but not to scrape other "form-groups" in different entries.

Here's my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
import time


word = ["peculiar"]
source = "https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/"
for word in word:
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(source + word) as url:
            s = url.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
        try:
            form_groups = soup.find('span', {'class': 'form-groups'}).text
            y = form_groups
        except:
            y = "no form_groups"

        print(word + "#" + y)
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        print("No result for " + word)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Any input is much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is embedded in your question. You are scanning the whole page for `span`s of class `form-groups`, but you are actually interested in the hierarchy of the dictionary article: you only want `span`s of that class when they are direct children of a `section` of class `gramb`, and not lower down in the tree.

*Edit: Original answer was pasted from the wrong IDLE session*

```
section_grambs = soup.find_all('section', {'class': 'gramb'})
for section_gramb in section_grambs:
    for child in (section_gramb.children):
        if child.name == "span" and "form-groups" in child.attrs["class"]:
            y = child.text
        else:
            y = "no form groups"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into my problem! I really appreciate it:) However, it still doesn't work. For example, "peculiar" still scrapes the 'form-groups' under entry 2.1. I believe `'section', {'class': 'gramb'}` covers all entries, that's why it scrapes all form-groups' available. Thanks again!

Comment: It still doesn't work. For example, "peculiar" still scrapes the 'form-groups' under entry 2.1. I believe 'section', {'class': 'gramb'} covers all entries, that's why it scrapes all form-groups' available.

Comment: Hello! I just saw your new edited answer. However,     y = form_groups.text has the issue of "Unresolved reference 'form_groups'". What should I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt reply! The code runs but the result is not what I expected. For the word "acclimatize", the form-group should return "often acclimatize to" or "be/become acclimatized to" but yours return ""no form groups":( I really appreciate your help along the way!

Comment: I realized that source = "https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/" and source = "https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/" will result in different results. Maybe my problem has something to do with it?

Comment: I don't know why but I don't get the same results as you, even from the exact same URL. What I get for *acclimatize* doesn't match your screenshot. Something to do with where I live, I suppose. So a part of this has been sort of guesswork,and that increases the error rate. And in particular it doesn't show *acclimatize to*. In fact it doesn't define the word at all, just cross-references to *acclimate*.

Comment: I accepted your answer:) I figured it has sth to do with the website, not your code. I figured using lxml and xpath might work but I could never get lxml to work. Nevermind. Thank you so much for your help along the way. Really appreciate it!